# Python Flask: Cannot find a way to set the default value in SelectForm (Flask WTF)

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I cannot find any solution to set the default value in `SelectForm` (Flask WTF). I would like the default value (i.e. the initial value of the dropdown) to be set dynamically.

I am using **Flask-WTF 0.14.3**.

I am using the following macro to render all the fields in the template:

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
    <dt>{{ field.label }}
    <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
    {% if field.errors %}
        <ul class=errors>
        {% for error in field.errors %}
        <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
    </dd>
{% endmacro %}
```

I use my custom form that inherits from `FlaskForm` class. Such form contains some fields of type `SelectField`. When configuring the class, I do not set the default values, as they are not known (they should be set when the application runs).

I tried the following:

1. Setting the form as follows:

```py
@issues.route('/item', methods=["GET"])
def my_get():
    the_item = request.args["item"]
    # [BEGIN] This part will change in the following examples
    form = MyForm()
    form.my_item.choices = Item.query.with_entities(Item.id, Item.name).all()
    form.my_item.data = the_item
    # [END]
    return render_template("my_form.html", form=form)
```

Whereas this works for other fields, it does not in this case: dropdown starts with the first value.

2. Setting the form as follows:

```py
...
form = MyForm(my_item=the_item)
form.my_item.choices = Item.query.with_entities(Item.id, Item.name).all()
...
```

that gives `TypeError: 'UnboundField' object is not callable` on `<dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}`

3. Setting the form as follows:

```py
form = MyForm()
form.my_item.choices = Item.query.with_entities(Item.id, Item.name).all()
form.my_item.data = the_item
form.my_item.default = the_item
```

with the same results as way #1.

Could you please show me how to overcome such issue?
I thank you in advance.

Theo

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```py
class PostForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField(u'Title', validators=[Length(min=3, max=50, message='The title name must be between 3 and 20 digits long')],
                        render_kw={'class': '', 'rows': 50, 'placeholder': 'please input title'})
    blog_type = SelectField(label=u'Cate',
                            default=0,
                            coerce=int)
    blog_level = SelectField(label=u'Level', choices=[(1, 'public'), (2, 'private')], validators=[DataRequired()],
                             default=1, coerce=int)
    brief_content = TextAreaField(u'desc', validators=[DataRequired()])
    blog_img_file = FileField(label=u'image',
                              validators=[DataRequired(), FileAllowed(['png', 'jpg'], 'Only accept png and jpg images')],
                              render_kw={'value': "upload", 'class': 'btn btn-default'})
    body = CKEditorField('Body', validators=[DataRequired(message='please input content')])
    submit = SubmitField(u'Publish')

    def __init__(self, default=0, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        categories = BlogType.query.all()
        self.blog_type.choices = [(cate.id, cate.name) for cate in categories]
        self.blog_type.data = default
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess it works for you, but I am not a big fan of having the view depending on the DB...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it this way: this is how I get the choices after querying them:

```py
form.my_item.choices = Item.query.with_entities(Item.id, Item.name).all()
```

I made sure that the first item of `form.my_item.choices` list is my desired default value (i.e., the first item of such list *is the default*). I just needed to swap 2 elements of the list.

Hope this helps someone else too.

Greetings,

Theo